# Is there an established means of using AzureStor and arrow together in R?

Tags: r, azure-blob-storage, apache-arrow

In the [arrow R guide](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/r/articles/fs.html#disabling-the-use-of-environment-variables) there's info about using S3 buckets but nothing about using Azure cloud storage.  There's an unrelated package [AzureStor](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/AzureStor/vignettes/intro.html) which connects to Azure Storage but uses different syntax so they don't (seemingly) work together.

Is there a an existing adaptation or easy way to adapt the `AzureStor` syntax over to a `FileSystem` class that arrow can use?

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure but does Azure File System will help?

Something like mentioned in the link below:
https://www.educba.com/azure-file-storage/

Comment: Not related to the problem at hand.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).